# WSL2 - Docker not running on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Following the official documentation I have installed Docker but it is not starting. I'm running Microsoft's Ubuntu image for WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux), fully updated.

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Since the distribution is not started with systemd I have to start Docker manually:

```
service docker start
```

However Docker is not starting:

```
pomatti@NT-03024:/mnt/c/Users/evandro.pomatti.HBSISNET$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker [ OK ]
pomatti@NT-03024:/mnt/c/Users/evandro.pomatti.HBSISNET$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
```

I did run this procedure plenty of times on Linux and it always worked, but I don't know where to start in the WSL2 environment.

Comment: Step One: Use Docker for Windows. If you really don't want to use that check out logs to figure out why Docker isn't coming up.

Comment: See this video about [Docker Desktop Integration with WSL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_PpmELU_PM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've abandoned running Docker on the VM to just use it via Windows as the comments instructed me. It builds up for a better experience.